# converting boost::shared_array to zfparray1

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, iterator

I need to use zfp to decompress an array of data. According to [documentation](https://zfp.readthedocs.io/en/release0.5.4/tutorial.html#compressed-c-arrays) , zfparray1 type can used to decompress. However, the input is boost::shared_array type. I used

```
zfp::array1d raw_data{std::begin(raw_msgpack.data), std::end(raw_msgpack.data)};
```

to translate the data. It doesn't work fine. I got error

```
/usr/include/c++/8/initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
MsgpackDeserializer.cpp:39:53: note:   ‘boost::shared_array<char>’ is not derived from ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’
    zfp::array1d raw_data{std::begin(raw_msgpack.data), std::end(raw_msgpack.data)};
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the https://github.com/LLNL/zfp/blob/develop/examples/simple.c example, which defines a very simple compress/decompress function:

```
/* compress or decompress array */
static int
compress(double* array, size_t nx, size_t ny, size_t nz, double tolerance, zfp_bool decompress)
{
```

Comment: but it is using c interface. I am wondering to use c++ version